# Can I ask for translation of some poems?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I saw on twitter two poems and I need help with translation but I'm not sure if I can use stackexchange for it?

If not suggest me maybe resources where people can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://reddit.com/r/translator might be a good bet